# Item price factor compared to items in same subgroup

Tags: python, pandas, price

I have a large dataset including items, subgroups of the items and prices. The simplified version looks as follows:

| Item | Subgroup | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 10 |
| 2 | A | 12 |
| 3 | B | 2 |
| 4 | B | 6 |
| 5 | B | 4 |
| 6 | C | 7 |
| 7 | C | 8 |

I want to add the column `relativePrice'. This column indicates the price of each item compared to the average price of the items in the same subgroup. The value equals the price of the item devided by the average price of the items in the same subgroup rounded to two decimals. For item 1 for example this variable equals 10/11 = 0.91. Hence, I want to get to:

| Item | Subgroup | Price | relativePrice |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 10 | 0.91 |
| 2 | A | 12 | 1.09 |
| 3 | B | 2 | 0.50 |
| 4 | B | 6 | 1.50 |
| 5 | B | 4 | 1 |
| 6 | C | 7 | 0.93 |
| 7 | C | 8 | 1.07 |

Can anyone help me coding this problem in Python?

Comment: What are you using to store this data? Are you using json or simply a python list?

Comment: `df['Price'] / df.groupby('Subgroup')['Price'].transform('mean')`

Comment: `df['relativePrice'] = df['Price']/df.groupby('Subgroup')['Price'].transform('mean')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) and [`round`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_round.asp):

```
In [352]: df['relativePrice'] = round(df['Price'] /df.groupby('Subgroup')['Price'].transform('mean'), 2)

In [353]: df
Out[353]: 
   Item Subgroup  Price  relativePrice
0     1        A     10           0.91
1     2        A     12           1.09
2     3        B      2           0.50
3     4        B      6           1.50
4     5        B      4           1.00
5     6        C      7           0.93
6     7        C      8           1.07
```

Comment: Thanks! This code was exactly what I needed.